Angular 18, mat-select binding not working with formControlName property
The Angular custom contol componet have following code
@Component({
  selector: 'material-custom-control',
  templateUrl: './material-custom-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-custom-control.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: RapportUiMaterialSelectComponent },
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: CustomErrorMatcher }
  ]
})

export class MaterialCustomControlComponent implements MatFormFieldControl<SelectList>, OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() options: Array<{ key: string, value: string }>;
....

have the html
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">    
    <mat-select 
    formControlName="selectedValue">
        <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let option of options" 
        [class.no-content]="!option.value"
        [value]="option.key">{{option.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</ng-container>

Using this custom control in other control like follwoing
  <material-custom-control formControlName="myName" [options]="myOptions">
  </material-custom-control>
  
    myOptions = [
    { key: '', value: '' },
    { key: 'Option1', value: 'Option1' },
    { key: 'Option2', value: 'Option2' },
    { key: 'Option3', value: 'Option3' },
  ];

On UI the Select componet is getting rendered without error but without any options.
This code was working in Angular 11, but after updating the application to Angular 18 it is not working.
If we remove the property formControlName="selectedValue" then the optins are getting loaded on the UI.
Please suggest what could be the problem and solution.

You have used formControlName in two places in the same element. Use input parameter for it as how you passing value to options.
It should be like
<material-custom-control [formctrlName]="myName" [options]="myOptions">
  </material-custom-control>

Create input parameter for formctrlName and use it in the mat-select

Its not woking after this change

You can use a DTO model class and NgModel. See example below
 <mat-select formControlName="myName" [(ngModel)]="DTO.myName">
 
 </mat-select>

DTO class
export class DTO {
myName!: string
}

